# Adding keystore to Ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-keystore

I am trying to connect to a WDSL webservice using SSL using Android 2.3.4. It uses a thawte certificate which isn't trusted.

I have created a keystore with intermediate and root certificates but do not know how to add the keystore to ksoap2.

Does anyone know if this is possible or a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I found this asnwer. It shows you how to create your own TrustManager and initiate it.

http://randomizedsort.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/step-to-step-guide-to-programming.html